# any element of open neighborhood of $e$ a connected lie group can be written as

Tags: lie-groups

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [About connected Lie Groups](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/137250/about-connected-lie-groups)

Could any one give me hint for the problem?

Let $G$ be a connected Lie group, and $U$ an open neighborhood of the group unit
$e$. Show that any $g\in G$ can be written as a product $g = g_1.\dots.g_N$ of elements $g_i\in U.$

Comment: Here's a hint:  Let $X$ be the set of all $g\in G$ which can be written as such a product.  Show that $X$ is both open and closed.

Comment: @JasonDeVito Thank you :)

Comment: If you were able to figure it out from there, why not post your solution?